# Gradle variable initialization

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have got a little problem with variables / ext properties in gradle.
In my root project i have this:

```
task foo {
    println project.fooContent
}
```

in my child project `fooContent` is defined like this:

```
ext { fooContent='somethingProjectSpecific' }
```

When executing `:childproject:foo` it says variable is not set.

Do you know how to circumvent that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variable is not set since you try to print it at *configuration* phase. Try with an action (`<<`) it will be printed on *execution* phase:

```
task foo << {
    println project.fooContent
}
```

Comment: there is no evaluation error now. Thx for that. But the changes are causing another problem. This is my real-world-use-case.

rootproject:
`jar <<{
    manifest {
        attributes("foo": project.fooContent)
        }
}`
When i call the `:childproject:jar` now there is no error but my custom "foo" arrtibute is not going to be appended to the Manifest anymore.

Comment: @Mr.H., sure. What is the next problem?

Comment: The problem is as I said: I would like to define the functionality inside the root project ie: `jar <<{ manifest { attributes("foo": project.fooContent) } }` which means for all childprojects add the childs project.fooContent to its jars Manifest.MF. But this won't happen since i used `<<`

Comment: could you please have a look at. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178423/gradle-multi-project-build-property-undefined)